# count to 10 only odds PL/SQL

Tags: sql

I was able to figure this out, but does anyone have a more efficient way to count to 10 and only print out odds in PL/SQL?

```
DECLARE

v_count integer := 0;
v_num integer := 1;


BEGIN
WHILE V_NUM <=8
    LOOP

        EXIT WHEN v_count = 10; 
        v_num := v_num + 1;

        IF (v_num MOD 2) = 1 
        THEN v_count := v_count + 1;
           dbms_output.put_line(v_num);
        END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    v_num integer;
BEGIN
    FOR v_num IN 1..10 LOOP
        IF (v_num MOD 2) = 1 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_num);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, if you want to minimise the number of loop iterations (you're then not really counting to 10 any more):

```
DECLARE
    v_num integer;
BEGIN
    FOR v_num IN 0..4 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(v_num*2+1);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would phrase the 2nd version as "if you want to minimise the loop interations".

Comment: Thanks, updated the text according to your suggestion.

Comment: If it answers your question, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: opps sry new to this ...!